# Express.js mongoose: TypeError Cannot set property of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose

I created an `UserSchema` and added a method in which i try to set it's property `name`:

```
import mongoose, { Schema } from 'mongoose'

const UserSchema = new Schema({
  name: String
})

UserSchema.methods.setName = (name) => {
  this.name = name + '123'
}

exports default mongoose.model('User', UserSchema)
```

I imported the object and called the method from the controller I created:

```
import User from './User'

exports.signup = (request, response) => {
  const name = 'Ignas'

  const UserModel = new User
  UserModel.setName(name)

  ...
}
```

For some reason it throws me an error:

> TypeError: Cannot set property "name" of undefined

How could `this` be undefined?

If I modify a method passing the object I could make it working as I want, but it looks dirty and incorrect since all I want to do is to change object´s property through it´s method..

```
// modified method of Schema
UserSchema.methods.setName = (User, name) => {
  User.name = name + '123'
}

// modified call from the controller
UserModel.setName(name)
```

Comment: I think it's a context issue. Try to **bind** the instance to the function. UserSchema.methods.setName = function (name) {
  this.name = name + '123'
}.bind(UserSchema)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arrow functions don't bind its own `this`. They use *lexical* `this`. Arrow functions lexically bind their context so `this` actually refers to the originating context. This is called lexical scoping. And what lexical scoping means:

> Lexical scoping (sometimes known as static scoping ) is a convention
>   used with many programming languages that sets the scope (range of
>   functionality) of a variable so that it may only be called
>   (referenced) from within the block of code in which it is defined.

You have more explanations about this issue in [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#No_separate_this) for example.

At the end, what it happens is that it will look for `this` in all parent's context until it finds it, and in your case, because in the module there is not a definition of `this` anywhere, returns `undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `Arrow function` syntax, `this` keyword with arrow function has some things mess.

Hotfix: Use old school function syntax

```
UserSchema.methods.setName = function(name) {
  this.name = name + '123'
}
```